# How to insert an empty row in every three rows displayed in a table (ui:repeat)

Tags: jsf

I have a bootstrap table with more than 50 rows, what i want to achieve is to have
an empty row that will act as a divider in every three rows being displayed.

this is my xhtml code.

```
<tbody>
    <ui:repeat var="person" value="#{myBean.listOfPersons}">
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{person.firstName}"/> </td>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{person.lastName}"/> </td>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{person.age}"/> </td>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</tbody>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
<tbody>
    <ui:repeat var="person" value="#{myBean.listOfPersons}" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{person.firstName}"/> </td>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{person.lastName}"/> </td>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{person.age}"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <ui:fragment rendered="#{(status.index + 1) % 3 eq 0}">
            <tr style="height:30px;">
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
        </ui:fragment>

    </ui:repeat>
</tbody>
```

> Use the `varStatus` attribute to get the index of the iteration `#{status.index}`.
>
> The `rendered` attribute determine whether the component will be rendered or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, gonna try it when I get home